# AJAX JSON and routing in cakephp

Tags: php, ajax, json, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to implement a search module by using AJAX.

There is an index.ctp file in my Items Controller and I have linked my index.ctp file of Items to my search.ctp file which is present under Pages controller as below:

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Search Products'),['controller'=>'Pages','action' => 'search']) ?></li>
```

For the search.ctp pages the URL displayed is :
http://onlineelectronic.com/pages/search

In my search.ctp file the code is as follows:

```
    <head>
    <title> Search Results</title>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', array('inline' => false));?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Submit1").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/Items/searchData",
                    data: {
                        name: "search"
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#resultField").html("Loading...");
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        jQuery('#resultField').val(response);
                    },
                    error: function(response, error) {
                        alert("Search :Error"+response.error());
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    global: false
                });
               return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<div>
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Search Item') ?></legend>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('search',['label'=>'Search']);
        ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?= $this->Form->button('Search Items',['label'=>'Submit1']); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>

</div>

<div id="resultField">

</div>
```

In my ItemsContoller page the searchData method is implemented like this:

```
    class ItemsController extends AppController
{


    public $helpers = ['Form', 'Html', 'Time'];

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }

    public function search(){
    //dummy
    }

    /**
     *obtains search result for a given string.
     */
    public function searchData()
    {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        echo "here";
        $search_data=[];
        var_dump($search_data);
        //$search_results = [];
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $search_data= $this->request->data;
            $search_data=implode("|",$search_data);
            $search_results = $this->Items->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Items.itemName LIKE'=>"%$search_data%")));
            if(!empty($search_results)) {
                $this->set(compact($search_results));
                $this->set('_serialize',array('search_results'));
                return json_encode($search_results);
            }
        }

    }



    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view','search','searchData']);


    }
}
```

My issue is that  the SearchData method  is not being called and I am not getting any javascript errors also.How do i make sure that the method gets called on pressed after pressing the button.Is it due to the url in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 possible problems. First in ItemsController, you have to allow searchData method

```
// change this line
$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view','search']);
// to this
$this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view','searchData']);
```

also make sure, that you have proper jQuery selector

```
// try to change this line
<?= $this->Form->button('Search Items',['label'=>'Submit1']); ?>
// to this
<?= $this->Form->button('Search Items',['id'=>'Submit1']); ?>
```

**Edit:** make more corrections to javascript:

1. Data passed with ajax should be double quoted

   ```
   data: {
       name: "search"
   },
   ```
2. add `return false;` to the end of click handler, so you prevent submiting form and reloading page

Also note that you must have template for searchData in `Template/Items/search_data.ctp`

Comment: I have made both the changes but it does not seem to have any effect.
I have now included the search.ctp file under Items/Template and from there I am calling the searchData method by using the url:'/Items/searchData';
 I will edit my post so that it reflects my current code
What i have observed is that form tries to call action method search() from Items Controller so I included a dummy method in controller with no code.But from the ajax code I am not able to access searchdata and beforeSend does not work @Roman

Comment: I edited my answer, i believe your problem is only in javascript. AJAX should call `searchData` method, `search` method is not neccessary

Comment: Edited the code like above as you have mentioned ,now I am getting an alert which is displayed on error in json.
The message i get is "Search:Error[object Object].
Why is the object returned as error

Comment: You have echo and debug statements in `searchMethod`, ajax expects only valid json to be returned (due to dataType). So try to remove all these debug staments. To test it, you should be able to open `/items/searchData` in browser and see only _JSON encoded_ plaintext.

Comment: POST onlineelectronic.com/Items/searchData 500 (Internal Server Error) send @ jquery.min.js:4 m.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4 (anonymous function) @ search:31 m.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3 These errors are observed on my browser console. Please note i have removed all debug prints as you have suggested on giving/Items/searchData I get blank page In cakephp application 3.0 since we can also see requests on cakephp application in the post data nothing is being sent
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kinwcybp7exmog/error.jpg?dl=0

@Roman

Comment: now you're getting error somewhere in searchData method. Try to remove line `return json_encode($search_results);`, since controller method can return only **Response object** and set results like `$this->set('search_results', json_encode($search_results));`. Also make sure, that you set `$search_results` to View, even if result of find is empty. Content of your `search_data.ctp` should be like this: `<?php echo $search_results;`