# how to send json file to dataTable in cakephp2.6

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

Iam looking for to deploy a dataTable for my form search to get result from Apache solr using solarium Client of php and for each result I transform it to JSON format like below: in my action search:

```
public function search() {
    if($_POST){
    // get a select query instance
            $query = $client->createSelect()
                   ->setQuery($forsearch )
                   ->addParam('wt','json');
    // this executes the query and returns the result
                $resultset = $client->select($query);

                $this->response->body(json_encode($result));
    }
    }
```

how can I send json file to view to much the url in this fuction:

```
$('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable({
                "processing": true,
               "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                "url": "http://localhost/solr/users/search.json",

            });
```

I cant use $this->autoRender = false; because i need input forsearch from search.ctp to get $resulset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857078/ajax-json-and-routing-in-cakephp)  is verry helpfull in my case. this question is close. thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Ello, mate.
On the controller function, you must format the response into an object with an index "data", and that index must contain a list containing lists that will be displayed by Datatables , it must look like this:

```
{ 
    data: [
        [field, field, field, field],
        [field, field, field, field]........
    ]
}
```

Dont forget to implode() some fields, in your case, you must implode() the field 'competence_txt' to make it become a string.

Check [Datatables oficial website](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already test with a static json file and display hes content to data Table succefly. Now I am looking for genarate automatically json file to send to data Table.

Comment: Considering **$response** = your response, you should format it to a json that datatables can read.

Try:

`$arr_response = json_decode($response, true);
$arr_data = array('data' => array());
foreach($arr_response['response']['docs'] as $key => $val)
{
 $this_data = array();
 if(is_array($val))
 {
  $imploded_val = implode(',', $val); 
  array_push($this_data, $imploded_val);
 }
 else
 {
  array_push($this_data, $val);
 }
 
 array_push($arr_data['data'], $this_data);
}
echo json_encode($arr_data);
`